# Conversion binary floating point to hex floating point

Tags: floating-point, binary, hex, octal

For example I have `0 100 1110` `sign exponent mantisa` this is equal to `3.75`. How to convert it to hexadecimal or octal form? I have searched really hard for few hours. Please help.

Could you help me here `100` is `4`   `1110` is `7/8` no way that's `(7/8) * 2^4` is `3.75`.

Answer (score 1):

Sign should be obvious.

Mantissa means, 1 + 1/2*first bit + 1/4*second bit + 1/8*third bit... Sound familiar? It's basically binary counting, except it's 'after the decimal point'.

Exponent means, multiply the mantisa by 2^exponent. But how do you get to the bits in `exponent` to what value it represents? I did some googling, and apparently if the top bit is set and the rest are `0` (10, 100, 1000..., etc) then you have `1`, if it's `101` you have `2`, etc. Meaning if it's `011` you have `0`, `010` you have `-1` and so on. So in this case we have `1` for exponent.

So in this case you want to calculate 1.875 (mantisa) *2^1 (2^exponent) and make it positive (sign).

Read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format (it's for the double precision size, but all the principles should 'apply' to any size floating point)

EDIT: Here's a better explanation about the exponent.

First off, in IEEE floating points, the smallest and largest value for exponent have special meanings - all zeroes means 'this is a zero or a subnormal number', all ones means 'this is infinity or NaN'. So, even though we have three bits of exponent - `000` to `111`, only `001` to `110` express normal exponents - that's only 6 values.

Now, something called 'exponent' bias is used to turn this 1...6 range into negative and positive values - in particular, you want a -2...3 range (with the largest positive exponent > the magnitude of the largest negative exponent, so you can't get overflow by doing 1/`smallest normalized number`. However, 1/`denormalized number` can produce `Infinity`.)

We get this by taking the value in exponent, and if it is not a special case we subtract 3 from its binary value and take this as its exponent value.

`0 100 1110` is therefore

`0` -> positive sign

`100` -> binary value 4, subtract 3, exponent 1

`1110` -> 1 + 7/8

(1+7/8)*2^1 = 3.75

Comment: I know how to get binary floating point, I asked about conversion.

Comment: Oh, then it's really easy, you just - well, the other answer beat me to it :)

Comment: Could you help me here `100` is `4`   `1110` is `7/8` no way that's `(7/8) * 2^4` is `3.75`.

Comment: @Robert Kilar: Please read my exit to the answer. Your problem is not knowing about biased exponents :)

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the bits, as if it was an integer. Ignore the fact that you're dealing with a floating point number.

`01001110` converts to `4E` in hex, because `0100` is `4` and `1110` is `E`. (Notice how I group in fours.)

Same for octal, it becomes `116`, because `01` is `1`, `001` is `1` and `110` is `6`. (Notice how I group in threes, except for the very first group.)

Comment: But the problem is that `4E` is not 3.75. How to convert it back to the decimal.